# How to randomly generate 1000 sequences of 6 digit number

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, random

I want to generate 1000 number randomly and put the result in a rich text box ,but the result I got from my code is just one number appearing in the rich text box !!

```
 private Random _random = new Random();
 int min = 000000;
 int max = 999999;
 string s;  
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
       s = _random.Next(min, max).ToString("D6") + "\n";
    }
    richTextBox1.Text = s;
 }
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter it's a rich text box with multiline property

Comment: Just to confirm: You're happy with duplicate numbers appearing in the list, right?

Comment: So, they're numbers in the range of 0 - 999999 and if the number has fewer than six digits pad it with 0s at the beginning?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overriding the value of s each time you get your next number. Instead you have to add the number to a list. Something like this would work.

```
List<string> numbers = new List<string>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        numbers.Add(_random.Next(min, max).ToString("D6"));
    }
    richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it's working I would be thankfull if you accept my answer :)

Answer (score 5):

As most of the answers here using the .net class **Random** i would not use it, because in a direct comparison it doesn't creates **strong** random numbers.

Example:
[image]

So if you want **strong** random numbers you should refrain from using **Random** and use the **RNGCryptoServiceProvider** from the namesapace **System.Security.Cryptography**

ExampleCode:

```
private RNGCryptoServiceProvider _random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider ();
int min = 000000;
int max = 999999;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] results = new int[1000];
    var buffer = new byte[4];
    int min = 100000;
    int max = 999999;
    for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++) {
        while(results[i] < min || results[i] > max)
        {
            _random.GetBytes(buffer);
            results[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
        }
        richTextBox1.Text += results[i].toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you generate that image of points?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson It's been a while since I did that, but I generated two values for each point and just drew them on a canvas. I don't know anymore how many points (> 10000)  I generated, but I know I only restricted the values to be >= 0

Answer (score 4):

Problem is that you actually overwrite at each iteration the string s. You need to append the number to the old ones.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    s += _random.Next(min, max).ToString("D6") + "\n";
}
richTextBox1.Text = s;
```

You could also use [`AppendText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(_random.Next(min, max).ToString("D6") + "\n");
}
```

Suggestion by [Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson): When generating such a large string it is very adviseable to use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). Is has much better performance than a normal concatenation of strings:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8000);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    sb.AppendLine(_random.Next(min, max).ToString("D6"));
}

richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I strongly suggest that you use a `StringBuilder` to create the string.

Comment: @MatthewWatson smart Idea! thank you. Was way too inpatient when writing the answer ;) to think thoroughly

Answer (score 4):

You actually need to concatenate the result with previous calculated result, right now it is replacing the string value in `s` every time loop executes and you end up only with the last value in `s`, a quick fix is to use contatination using `+`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
  s+= _random.Next(min, max).ToString("D6") + "\n"; // now it keeps previous values as well
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s += _random.Next(min, max).ToString("D6") + "\n";
  ^
  |
  ---- You're missing this plus sign
```

Answer (score 0):

just You need to add ' + ' for the `richtextbox1` as like below

try this one

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            s = _random.Next(min, max).ToString("D6") + "\n";

             richTextBox1.Text + = s;
        }

    }
```

Comment: No,that won't work. It would just show the last generated number

Answer (score 0):

on this line of code you override the `Text` of `richTextBox1`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
       s = _random.Next(min, max).ToString("D6") + "\n";
    }
    richTextBox1.Text = s;
```

just change it to (add a `+` after `s`)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
       s += _random.Next(min, max).ToString("D6") + "\n";
    }
    richTextBox1.Text = s;
```

Comment: That won't work.It would just show the last generated number

Answer (score 0):

Note that the maxValue or [`Random.Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2dx6wyd4) is exclusive, so 999999 is never genereted.

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Repeat(new Random(), 1000)
                        .Select(r => r.Next(1000000).ToString("D6")); // the same new Random() instance is used for all .Next

richTextBox1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", numbers);
```

Or a bit more efficient:

```
richTextBox1.Text = Enumerable.Repeat(new Random(), 1000).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(7000)
                , (b, r) => b.AppendFormat("{0:D6}\n", r.Next(1000000))).ToString(0, 6999);
```